# Ошибка eslint и prettier

Tags: vue.js, vue3, сборка, eslint, prettier

Создал vue проект с файлом App.vue

```
/* eslint-disable */

<template>
    <div>

    </div>
</template>

<script>

</script>

<style>

</style>
```

В результате при выполнении команды npm run serve выдает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как устранить ошибки.

```
You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
ERROR in [eslint]                                                                                                                                          
D:\OSPanel\domains\vue3-course\src\App.vue
   1:21  error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
   2:1   error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
   3:11  error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
   4:1   error  Replace `····<div>␍⏎␍⏎····</div>␍` with `··<div></div>`  prettier/prettier
   7:12  error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
   8:1   error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
   9:9   error  Replace `␍⏎␍⏎</script>␍` with `</script>`                prettier/prettier
  12:1   error  Delete `␍`                                               prettier/prettier
  13:8   error  Replace `␍⏎␍⏎</style>` with `</style>⏎`                  prettier/prettier

✖ 9 problems (9 errors, 0 warnings)
  9 errors and 0 warnings potentially fixable with the `--fix` option.


webpack compiled with 1 error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще всего отказаться от pretier. В каталоге проекта в файле .eslintrc.js в секции 'extends' удалите строчку

"plugin:prettier/recommended",

Comment: у меня эта строка находится в файле package.json.

Comment: Значит - надо удалить там. Не забудте удалить запятую в предыдущей строчке. Но можно поступить и по другому. Перед запуском проекта наберите npm run lint  Эта команда обработает все ошибки форматирования и внесет исправления. И настроить редактор, которым пользуетесь.